# how to implement globalization in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to implement globalisation in ASP.NET MVC 4 site , can you please help me in finding tutorial or example from where I can pick up.

Comment: what kind of Globalization you want? FOr session or anything else?

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32764989)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Beginner's Tutorial on Globalization and Localization in ASP.NET
  MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati)
- [ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)
- [Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC
  3, JavaScript and jQuery - Part 1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)